# Separating arc segments on a canvas with transparency

Tags: javascript, canvas

I guess I'll just have to show it:

```js
function drawSector(ctx, cxy, rInner, rOuter, radStart, radWidth, color) {
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.arc(cxy, cxy, rInner, radStart, radStart + radWidth);
 ctx.lineTo(cxy + rOuter * Math.cos(radStart + radWidth), cxy + rOuter * Math.sin(radStart + radWidth));
 ctx.arc(cxy, cxy, rOuter, radStart + radWidth, radStart, true);
 ctx.lineTo(cxy + rInner * Math.cos(radStart), cxy + rInner * Math.sin(radStart));
 ctx.fillStyle = color;
 ctx.fill();
 ctx.stroke();
}
function makecircle(diam) {
 var canv = document.createElement("canvas");
    canv.width = diam; canv.height = diam;
 document.getElementById("c").appendChild(canv);
 
 var ctx = canv.getContext("2d");
 ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,1)";
 ctx.lineWidth = 5;
 
 
 var centerXY = diam / 2;
 var centerRadius = diam / 6;
 var sectorHeight = (centerXY - centerRadius) / 5 - 2;
 var sectorAngle = Math.PI * 2 / 15;
 
 for (var r = 0; r < 15; r++) {
  for (var h = 0; h < 5; h++) {
   drawSector(ctx, centerXY, centerRadius + sectorHeight * h, centerRadius + sectorHeight * (h + 1), r * sectorAngle, sectorAngle, "rgba(255,0,0,0.5)");
  }
 }
 
 
}

makecircle(500);
```

```css
body {
    background-color:darkgreen;
  }
```

```html
<div id="c"></div>
```

So there is this circle divided into sectors. I want there to be a little space between each sector (currently illustrated by black stroke). Cutting the height/angle width of each sector works but since its a constant angle it widens outwards and I don't like the look.

I figured there must be a way to draw stroke ontop of the circle and have that area become transparent again, is there? (also I can't ditch filling each sector separately since I'm going to make them different colors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "erase" existing pixels by setting `globalCompositeOperation='destination-out'`.

Then draw your radiating lines. Instead of being visible, the radiating lines will erase any existing pixels that the lines overlap.

When you're done erasing, be sure to set globalCompositeOperation back to its default of 'source-over'.